# Can the StackOverflow Company create a Generic Question Answer Forum with an API?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, api

You guys have the best, most easiest to use, simplest question and answer wall I have ever encountered, and you're pumping out new ones all the time.

I, and I'm sure many other people, would really LOVE to have this system ourselves to use on our client projects.

What I'm thinking is something like [UserVoice](https://uservoice.com/), where you can add an "Ask Question" button on myClientsSite.com and it takes me to "StackOverflowOpenAPI.com" or something, where we can run our own micro Q/A for the client.  And then you could have an XML/JSON alternative so we could programmatically read/write questions/answers to the StackOverflow-like open hub.

You guys are the most qualified on the internet to do something like this.  Is this something you're thinking about in the future???

Thanks so much,
Lance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you seen http://stackexchange.com?